# Cant call javascript function in php file (Laravel)

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

Im curently learning laravel with QR code. I use the code that I got from [github](https://github.com/schmich/instascan). Its working fine when I run the html file. But when I add to my code in php file (Laravel) I get some error.

The error:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>   Call to undefined function formatName() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\museumadityawarman\resources\views\topups\scan_qrcode.blade.php)

The error points out to this part of my view:

```
<span v-if="camera.id == activeCameraId" :title="formatName(camera.name)" class="active">{{ formatName(camera.name) }}</span>

<li v-for="scan in scans" :key="scan.date" :title="scan.content"><script type="text/javascript">{{scan.content}}</li>
```

I've tried to change from

```
{{ formatName(camera.name) }}
```

To

```
<script>formatName(camera.name);</script>
```

This does fix the error message but I still can't get the value.

This is some of Javascript code:

```
 methods: {
    formatName: function (name) {
      return name || '(unknown)';
    },
    selectCamera: function (camera) {
      this.activeCameraId = camera.id;
      this.scanner.start(camera);
    }   }
```

Thanks, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What is `camera`? Is it a php variable or javascript variable? You can't mix PHP and javascript codes, because PHP only runs before the page is sent to the browser, and javascript after.

Comment: camera is from javascript. Im not use php command there, I just add from html that i get form github to Laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put an @ before the {{ formatName(camera.name) }}

```
@{{ formatName(camera.name) }}
```

Look at the Laravel doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks:

> Since many JavaScript frameworks also use "curly" braces to indicate a given expression should be displayed in the browser, you may use the @ symbol to inform the Blade rendering engine an expression should remain untouched

EDIT:

Since you look like you are using vue.js, you could also use the directive v-text like so :

```
<span v-if="camera.id == activeCameraId" :title="formatName(camera.name)" class="active" v-text="formatName(camera.name)"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks bro. I will try your suggestions. And i will comment if my problem fixed :)

Comment: Glad I could help! Have a nice day :-)